# altbeacon and Android10 foreground service permissions

Tags: altbeacon

I am attempting to upgrade my beacon app to Android 10 and it appears I need to add a
`<service android:foregroundServiceType="location"/>` to the apps manifest. This however also requires an android:name entry for the service class. What is this service class if I am using the following to create the service from within an activity?

iBeaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456);

If this service is set correctly I understand that I do not need to specify the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION user-permission. Will Android prompt for permission 'Allow all the time' on first run of app or is something else required?

Comment: I believe you do need to get background location permission for this to work.  This does require adding that permission to the manifest and requesting it at runtime in your code.  What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Yes it would appear that BACKGROUND is still required as per developer.android.com/training/location/permissions. I will mark this as correct as it helped me set out the correct permissions flow in my app. Thaks